# Testlink Database Error Message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: putty, testlink

I almost finish in creating a Testlink server in our website. I just got an error when I am finishing my installation. Please help. Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvrD9.png)

Comment: The login data are incorrect. You have to provide the correct login data to access the database. Which database are you using?

Comment: Tnx I just create a new user with the same priveleges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It is solved. I didn't use my root login/username password.  I Just create a new user with all grant privileges and then use it for that two login credentials.